# gnome keyring pkcs11 warning

Tags: key, gnome, pkcs#11

I get a gnome-keyring warning when I try to do many different things from the command line, like svn. Example:

```
$ lp README.txt 
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /run/user/dargaud/keyring-kAKdPw/pkcs11: No such file or directory
request id is lpsc0204pnb-366 (1 file(s))
```

/run/user/dargaud/keyring-kAKdPw/pkcs11 doesn't exist (there's only a 'control' socket in there).
I'm using Kubuntu, so why is anything trying to use the gnome keyring instead of kwallet in the first place ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can run it as startup job:

```
 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
```

Comment: Received this error when using git clone in backbox and adding this to startup solves it nicely.